# Compiling web app against Java 5, but String.isEmpty() is still being allowed?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am compiling my web app in Netbeans against Java EE 5.  I know that the `String.isEmpty()` function is only supported in Java 6.  Having said that, I can still compile my project using the `.isEmpty()` in my code.

How come Netbeans is allowing my web app to compile if I am compiling against Java EE 5?

Comment: For what class/interface? `isEmpty()` appears to be in the 1.5 API for `List`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty()

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Maybe he means Java 5's [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class? ([Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29))

Comment: @Brian Hard to tell when the OP doesn't even pay attention to their post.

Comment: Yes I'm here.  Sorry for the under hour delay.  Yes I am talking about the String class.

Comment: Which version of NetBeans are you using so I can check it?

Comment: Is the project a native (ant) based NetBeans project, or is it a Maven project?

Comment: I am using 7.2.1.  It appears that I setup my project as a Java EE 5 project, but it will still compile against whatever JRE is running on my OS.  Check this out: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754956/using-string-isempty-in-java-5-allowed)

Comment: Java EE versions and Java SE versions don't match. A Java EE 5 project can very well run on Java 7. You need to choose the appropriate JDK version.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue in my project, I have a class that is using String's class isEmpty() API, Eclipse IDE showing it as compilation issues, but still, it compiled .class file. How can it be tpossible?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler level is not equal to the JDK level you use for compiling. The compiler level only checks for the syntax and of course creates a different output. But the compiler itself will use the jdk on your classpath so if you compiled with java 5 option but with the java 6 jars on your classpath the code will compile without an error.
You should check your classpath.

Comment: Close but not quite. Nothing to do with classpath. The compiler uses whatever classes come with it. If you want it to use earlier JDK classes you need to use the -bootclasspath option.

Comment: True, messed up with the JDK which you configure to use in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

As many have pointed out, Java EE versions are not strictly tied with Java SE (JDK) versions. Mostly, they require a minimal Java SE version but are compatible with later versions.

Java EE 5 specification ([downloadable PDF here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/javaee-5.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)) says:

```
This specification requires that containers provide a Java Compatible™ runtime 
environment, as defined by the Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition, v5.0 specification 
(J2SE)
```

Since JSE versions are backwards compatible, you can take a container compatible with Java 5 and run it on top of Java SE 6 or Java SE 7.

You can check the compatibility level that Netbeans is using by checking the project "*Properties* > *Source* > *Source/Binary Format*"

If you still have doubts about "Java vs Java EE" you can look for several questions here on SO about the difference between Java SE and Java EE.