# Using String.isEmpty() in Java 5 allowed?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am compiling my web app in Netbeans against Java 5.

I'm using the String.isEmpty() in my code and it is still compiling?  How is this possible if String.isEmpty() is only supported by Java 6?

Comment: Try compiling it outside the IDE with a known version of Java. That may give you some insight. It probably has something to do with the Java version NetBeans is running with and the options set for NetBeans.

Comment: I will try that.  It's weird cause when I created the project in NetBeans I specifically selected Java EE 5 as the project version.

Comment: Java EE != Java SE - what matters is the underlying JRE version.

Comment: Java SE 5 != Java EE 5

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice, that's considered bad SO etiquette.